# Yield from a Tuple

Tags: scala, yield

Tuples and yield's: pretty common constructs. But to my surprise the following combination of them together is not so obvious how to make work:

```
 val edges = ((1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(1,6),(3,8),(4,9),(5,10),
 (1,7),(4,10))

  val edgesw = for (e <- edges) yield (e._1, e._2, 1.0)
   // e is interpreted as "any"
   // therefore e._1 and e._2 are invalid / do not compile
```

**UPDATE**

Adding the type parameters seems to help.. but why was it needed?

```
  val edgesw = for (e: (Int, Int) <- edges) yield (e._1, e._2, 1.0)
```

**Another update**  I neglected the Seq / Array notation!

```
 val edges = Seq((1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(1,6),(3,8),(4,9),(5,10),
 (1,7),(4,10))
```

Now the behavior is as expected:

```
  val edgesw = for (e <- edges) yield (e._1, e._2, 1.0)
 edgesw: Seq[(Int, Int, Double)] = List((1,2,1.0), (2,3,1.0), (3,4,1.0), (4,5,1.0), (1,6,1.0), (3,8,1.0), (4,9,1.0), (5,10,1.0), (1,7,1.0), (4,10,1.0))
```

Comment: @enzyme oh !  it is late. I forgot the Seq or Array in front!  Yes it is interesting that this worked at all!  The OP was updated to show the Seq in front.

Answer (score 1):

The following:

```
val edges = ((1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(1,6),(3,8),(4,9),(5,10), (1,7),(4,10))
val edgesw = for (e <- edges) yield (e._1, e._2, 1.0)
```

cannot be compiled. You need `Seq`as you mentioned So:

```
scala> val edges = Seq((1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(1,6),(3,8),(4,9),(5,10)) 
edges: Seq[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5), (1,6), (3,8), (4,9), (5,10))

scala> for (e <- edges) yield (e._1, e._2, 1.0)
res2: Seq[(Int, Int, Double)] = List((1,2,1.0), (2,3,1.0), (3,4,1.0), (4,5,1.0), (1,6,1.0), (3,8,1.0), (4,9,1.0), (5,10,1.0))
```

So the type inference works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like this:

```
  val edgesw = for (
    eany <- edges.productIterator;
    e = eany.asInstanceOf[(Int, Int)]
  ) yield (e._1, e._2, 1.0)
```

Every Tuple extends `Product` trait and therefore has:

```
def productIterator: Iterator[Any]
```

But because every Tuple members can include objects of different types `Product` can return only `Iterator[Any]`. Because of this `eany` type is `Any` and you should cast it to  `(Int, Int)`.

**UPDATE:**
Your UPDATE version doesn't work for me:

```
val edgesw = for (e: (Int, Int) <- edges) yield (e._1, e._2, 1.0)
```

I got the following error:

> value filter is not a member of ((Int, Int), ...) ...

Comment: Hmm.  Any time we see "asInstanceOf" it makes me skeptical. I would prefer to keep the "update" code shown above to this one. at least the explicit declaration (Int, Int)  does not involve casting.  OH! I found the problem - neglected the Seq (/Array) notation in front of the original data

Comment: Yes, using Seq (/Array) is more preferable than using Tuple to hold Tuples.